# Is it possible to stake DOT programmatically?

Tags: polkadot-js, staking

The title is pretty much it. Can I use Polkadot API to stake dot programmatically?

Can't seem to find that in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course.

You can read the documentation to learn how to submit extrinsics using Polkadot JS API:

https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.tx

Then, you just need to submit two extrinsics from the Staking Pallet:

1. Bond: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_staking/pallet/enum.Call.html#variant.bond

   This will lock a users funds so they can start to stake as a validator or nominator.
2. Either:

   1. Nominate: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_staking/pallet/enum.Call.html#variant.nominate

      If you want to set up the account as a nominator.
   2. Validate: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_staking/pallet/enum.Call.html#variant.validate

      If you want to set up the account as a validator.

There are more details needed specifically if you are setting up to be a validator which you can learn about here: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-validate-polkadot